# jwplayer6 giving error #2035 on Firefox for youtube videos

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

We are using JWplayer 6 version to our site and today I noticed that youtube videos are not working on Firefox, I am getting error (Error #2035). I have done google research but not worth, one of the post suggested to add player.swf and gt.swf. I did that but not working.

```
jwplayer.setup({
                file: _vFile,               
                image: _vImage,
                width: '100%',
                aspectratio: '16:9',
                stretching: 'fill',
                skin: '../jw-skin/vapor/vapor.xml'
            })
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Balram

Answer (score 2):

Set primary: 'html5' instead of primary: 'flash'

Comment: YouTube uses HTML5 video instead of Flash. By default, JW Player is in HTML5 mode as well. If you upgrade to the latest version, it will flip over to Flash automatically if it detects a video source that requires Flash. JW6 also was was default HTML5 but it depended on what source a publisher provided the player. If you upgrade to version 7, JW Player will automatically use the HTML5 YouTube API. (More on JW Player 7: http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/introducing-jw-player-7/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Up gradation to 6.12 solved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a Firefox plugin that was the culprit: "**Download YouTube Videos as MP4**" v.1.8.5
After deactivating this plugin, the #2035 error disappeared.

I read that also the "**HTTPS everywhere**" Firefox plugin is causing the same error with JWPlayer.